# Hashmap slower than string.find?

Tags: performance, rust, hashmap

I am doing exercises from leetcode as a way to learn Rust. One exercise involves finding the longest substring without any character repetition inside a string.

My first idea involved storing substrings in a string and searching the string to see if the character was already in it:

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn length_of_longest_substring(s: String) -> i32 {
        let mut unique_str = String::from("");
        let mut schars: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();   
        let mut longest = 0 as i32;
        for x in 0..schars.len()
        {
            unique_str = schars[x].to_string(); 
            for y in x+1..schars.len()
            {            
                if is_new_char(&unique_str, schars[y])
                {
                    unique_str.push(schars[y]);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            let cur_len = unique_str.len() as i32;
            if cur_len > longest {
                longest = cur_len;
            }
        }
        longest
    }
}

fn is_new_char ( unique_str: &str, c: char ) -> bool {
    if unique_str.find(c) == None
    {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }                
}
```

It works fine but the performance was on the low side. Hoping to shave a few ms on the "find" operation, I replaced unique_str with a HashMap:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
impl Solution {
    pub fn length_of_longest_substring(s: String) -> i32 {
        let mut hash_str = HashMap::new();
        let mut schars: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect(); 
        let mut longest = 0 as i32;
        for x in 0..schars.len()
        {            
            hash_str.insert(schars[x], x);
            for y in x+1..schars.len()
            {            
                if hash_str.contains_key(&schars[y]){
                    break;
                } else {
                    hash_str.insert(schars[y], y); 
                }
            }
            let cur_len = hash_str.len() as i32; 
            if cur_len > longest {
                longest = cur_len;
            }
            hash_str.clear();
        }
        longest
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, the `String.find()` version is 3 times faster than the HashMap in the benchmarks, in spite of the fact that I am using the same algorithm (or at least I think so). Intuitively, I would have assumed that doing the lookups in a hashmap should be considerably faster than searching the string's characters, but it turned out to be the opposite.

Can someone explain why the HashMap is so much slower? (or point out what I am doing wrong).

Comment: How big are your strings?

Comment: isn't something that can be solve in O(n) ?

Comment: @bk2204 Unsure. Test strings are run by leetcode and there are 987 test cases, so I expect some test strings are large, but since the strings are not displayed...

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, I think so, but that's not the issue. I don't care about the actual performance of the code, I am more interested in learning why, using the same algorithm, I get a better performance searching for characters inside a string as opposed to looking it up in a Hashmap. Is the hashmap.insert() operation more expensive than String.push()? Is it the look up? .... I am just trying to understand what's going on and rewriting the code as O(n) won't help me with that.

Comment: There can be a variety of reasons why a O(1) algorithm (hash lookup) might be slower than an O(n) algorithm (linear search) but without any particular knowledge about the actual data, it would mostly be speculation. There are some issues with this implementation, such as the fact that each hashmap entry contains the same thing as the key and the value, but that's probably irrelevant. `HashMap` uses a slow (cryptographic) hasher by default; you can do better by swapping it out for a fast one.

Comment: Note also the problem scales not just with the number of characters in the input string but with the number of *distinct* characters in the input stream, so if leetcode has a bunch of tests of the form `ababaabacabbcaabccababc` neither map nor `Vec` will ever get longer than n=3 which is tiny. But again this is just speculation.

Comment: Also Leetcode is bad for Rust because they impose some weird limitations on you that force you to use unidiomatic Rust. The `struct Solution` is one example.

Comment: Another thing is that rust uses a relatively slow but hash dos resistant hash function. Using a hash function optimized for small inputs such as [fnv](https://crates.io/crates/fnv) should be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to performance, one test is always better then 10 reasons.

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

fn main() {
    let start = std::time::SystemTime::now();
    let mut hasher = std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher::new();

    let s = "a";
    let string = "ab";
    for i in 0..100000000 {
         s.hash(&mut hasher);
         let hash = hasher.finish();
    }

    eprintln!("{}", start.elapsed().unwrap().as_millis());
}
```

I use debug build so that compiler would not optimize out most of my code.

On my machine taking 100M hashes above takes 14s. If I replace `DefaultHasher` with `SipHasher` as some comments suggested, it takes 17s.

Now, variant with string:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

fn main() {
    let start = std::time::SystemTime::now();

    let string = "abcde";
    for i in 0..100000000 {
        for c in string.chars() {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    eprintln!("{}", start.elapsed().unwrap().as_millis());
}
```

Executing this code with 5 chars in the string takes 24s. If there are 2 chars, it takes 12s.

Now, how does it answer your question?..

To insert a value into a hashset, a hash must be calculated. Then every time you want to check if a character is in the hashset, you need to calculate a hash again. Also there is some small overhead for checking if the value is in the hashset over just calculating the hash.

As we can see from the tests, calculating one hash of a single character string takes around the same time as iterating over 3 symbol string. So let's say you have a `unique_str` with value `abcde`, and you check if there is a `x` character in it. Just checking it would be faster with `HashSet`, but then you also need to add `x` into the set, which makes it taking 2 hashes against iterating 5-symbol string.

So as long as on average your `unique_str` is shorter than 5 symbols, string realization is guaranteed to be faster. And in case of an input string like `aaaaaaaaa....`, it will be ~6 times faster, then the `HashSet` option.

Of course this analisys is very simplistic and there can be many other factors in play (like compiler optimizations and specific realization of Hash and Find for strings), but it gives the idea, why in some cases `HashSet` can be slower then `string.find()`.

Side note: in your code you use `HashMap` instead of `HashSet`, which adds even more overhead and is not needed in your case...

Comment: *"I use debug build so that compiler would not optimize out most of my code"* - you should *never* benchmark unoptimized code. There are too many issues with it: for one, you aren't running what will end up being used in the field; two, things that should be zero-cost might end up with a cost; and three, seemingly small changes can make a big difference after optimizations. There are ways to address the constant-folding problem caused by an over-eager optimizer. Consider using something like [criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) that handles this and more for you.

Comment: `never` is a very strong word, in which I disagree with you. But thanks for the link for criterion.

Comment: Yes, never is a strong word and I used it because I felt it was appropriate. Unoptimized benchmarks only tell you about the performance of the unoptimized code, which is typically not what you care about. And thinking you can speculate on the performance of the optimized version based on it is naive for the reasons I listed above and more. Please don't make decisions based on bad data.